# How to add project to TFS source control in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, tfs, visual-studio-code

I have a project developed with **Angular 4** with **Visual Studio Code (version 1.18.0)**.
I need to add this project folder in TFS source control.
I have installed the **TFS extesion (version 0.6.0)** in Visual Studio Code, but I don't know how to map the project folder to TFS source control.
How I can do that?

Comment: Hi TeoVr81, any update on this? Did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I haven't tried yet, I'm busy with another activity at the moment. I will try that as soon as I can. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using the personal developed 3rd-party [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ivangabriele.vscode-tfs).

Suggest you use the official **[Visual Studio Team Services Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)** which released by Microsoft.

It supports both **TFVC** and **GIT** version control type.

> **Clone your Git repository**
>
> With Git, the extension uses the remote origin of your repository to
>   determine how to connect to Team Services (or your Team Foundation
>   Server), in most cases you will need to have a Git repository already
>   cloned locally. If you intend on cloning an existing repository, do so
>   before proceeding. If you do not have a Git repository cloned locally
>   but already have a Team Services account (or a Team Foundation Server
>   instance), you may create a local repository (via `git init`) and once
>   you set the "origin" remote for that local repository, the extension
>   will detect the change to the remote and attempt to contact the Team
>   Services account (or Team Foundation Server).
>
> **Create your TFVC workspace**
>
> With TFVC, the extension uses information about the current workspace
>   to determine how to connect to Team Services (or your Team Foundation
>   Server). Workspaces can be created using the Visual Studio IDE,
>   Eclipse or with the JetBrains IDEs (e.g, Android Studio, IntelliJ).
>
> *Note: At this time, you will need to have a local TFVC workspace already available on your local machine. More information about the
>   difference between the two types (and how to determine which one
>   you're using) can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-and-server-workspace-how-can-i-tell-which-one-im-working-with).*

You could also take a look at below videos to help get you started using the extension quickly:

- [Set up the Team Services extension for Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6gGfj8WOgg&feature=youtu.be) - *If
  you haven't used the extension before, this video will show you how
  to set it up, create a personal access token and get up and running.*
- [Walkthrough of the Team Services extension for Visual Studio
  Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sk6LrzQX4P8&feature=youtu.be) - *This is a walkthrough of most of the features of the Team
  Services extension.*
- [TFVC Source Code Control for Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be) - *This video shows
  you how to set up the TFVC support on Windows and demonstrates much
  of the functionality available for Team Foundation Version Control.*